# Azure DevOps Agent won't start and shows: Error 1 Incorrect Function - Service could not start

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I configured the build agent as a service but when I go to start the agent I get the error:

> Error  1 Incorrect Function - Service could not start

Azure DevOps Agent configured as a service but service does not start

Comment: have you checked the logs of the agent? check the `_diag` folder where you installed the agent.

Comment: have you checked the event log?

Comment: does the agent run when you use the `run.cmd` instead of running it as a service? If not, what error does that produce?

Comment: have you tried removign and addign the service?

Comment: i suspect that this missing information is causing the -1, cause "Does not work" is very little to go on to help you.

Comment: yes but thats the error i get, i agree its little to go on , ill check the above, it does run with the run command but not interactive

Comment: Running with the `run` command **is** running it interactively.

Comment: i need it to run as a service and thats wehen i get the error

Comment: ok ill answer my own question, when the config.cmd command is run, it allocates the network service as the account to run the service. However it does NOT automatically give permissions to where the agent folders are installed. So it fails to run. Stupid as this should be flagged when running the config.cmd command! The error message is nonsense and misleading. So if the agent is in c:\users\abc\agent you need to give the network service permissions to access that folder!

Answer (score 15):

I changed my user to **Local System** (*NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM*) in **services.msc** and it worked as intended.
[image: Azure Pipelines Agent Service]

Comment: Thank! it worked for GitHub Actions agent as well! 

It's 2021 and Microsoft better work on better error handling!

Comment: When I use Local System, the pipeline agent fails on all NuGet restores and other pipeline tasks. Network Service seems necessary for those to work right.

Comment: If you need to utilize network resources like NuGet and others, then: 
`NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` would be what you would need to utilize here.

Answer (score 8):

Copied from the comments:

> ok ill answer my own question, when the config.cmd command is run, it
>   allocates the network service as the account to run the service.
>   However it does NOT automatically give permissions to where the agent
>   folders are installed. So it fails to run. Stupid as this should be
>   flagged when running the config.cmd command! The error message is
>   nonsense and misleading. So if the agent is in c:\users\abc\agent you
>   need to give the network service permissions to access that folder!

Comment: In case you're upping a comment to an answer, it's custom to check the [community answer] checkbox.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks!

Comment: I found that if you extract the files to the directory c:\agent and run the config.cmd from there, that it works without further hassle.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when the service Azure Pipelines Agent in the machine is set with Log On As NETWORK SERVICE.

To resolve this, we need to

1. Right Click on the Azure Pipelines Agent
2. Properties
3. Click on LogOn tab
4. select Local System Account

The final output should be as per the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Running from C:\Agent worked perfect for me after struggling for a few days.

Comment: Added the final step for this as an answer below, meaning it is possible to run from another drive.

Answer (score 0):

> Running from C:\Agent worked perfect for me after struggling for a few days

Installing on a different drive will work but results in the error.
When you try this interactively, you realise the user doesn't have access to the root of the 'not C' drive.

Set 'Read' and 'List Contents' 'On this folder only' for the root of the drive so that the agent user can navigate past the root to the subfolder without revealing any other content.